# Parse beforeSave not triggering

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, before-save

I'm saving an object called 'Post' and I have a field called 'author' which is a Pointer to the Parse.User class. When I create a new 'Post' object, I pass the 'author' value as the Parse.User.id value to my Cloud Code function. Obviously, this would cause a type error on the 'author' field because it's a string and it's looking for a Parse.User object.

So to avoid this, I set up a beforeSave trigger that would check the value of 'author' and if it were of type string, query the Parse.User class for the user id and set the author value to be the returned Promise.

BUT.. my beforeSave trigger doesn't seem to get called for whatever reasons. Does anyone know why this could be happening? Initially I thought it was that my cloud function was running out of time, but my function is completing and giving me the type error that I expected since I'm passing a string into a Pointer field.

Here's my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Post', function (request, response) {
    var author = request.object.get('author');

    if (typeof author == 'string') {
        var qry = Parse.Query(Parse.User);
            qry.get(author, {
                success: function (user) {
                    request.object.set('author', user);
                    response.success();
                },
                error: function (u, err) {
                    response.error(err.message);
                }
            });

    } else {
        response.success();
    }
});

Parse.Cloud.define("post_update", function(request, response) {
    var vals = request.params;

    /**
     * Update if vals.objectId is set otherwise error
     */
    if (typeof vals['objectId'] != 'undefined' && typeof vals['objectId'] != 'null') {
        var qry = new Parse.Query('Post');
            qry.get(vals.objectId, {
               success: function (obj) {
                    delete vals.objectId;

                    obj.save(vals, {
                        success: function (nobj) {
                            response.success({redirect: false, object: nobj.id});
                        },
                        error: function (nobj, err) {
                            response.error(err.message);
                        }
                    });
               },
               error: function (obj, err) {
                    response.error(err.message + ': ' + vals.objectId);
               }
            });
    } else {
        response.error('Unable to update post');
    }
});
```

Here's my work-arround:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("post_update", function(request, response) {
    var vals = request.params;

    var onSave = {
        success: function (nobj) {
            response.success({redirect: false, object: nobj.id});
        },
        error: function (nobj, err) {
            response.error(err.message);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Update if vals.objectId is set otherwise error
     */
    if (typeof vals['objectId'] != 'undefined' && typeof vals['objectId'] != 'null') {
        var qry = new Parse.Query('Post');
            qry.get(vals.objectId, {
               success: function (obj) {
                    delete vals.objectId;

                    if (typeof vals['author'] === 'string') {
                        var uqry = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
                            uqry.get(vals.author, {
                                success: function (u) {
                                    vals.author = u;
                                    obj.save(vals, onSave);
                                },
                                error: function (u, err) {
                                    vals.author = null;
                                    obj.save(vals, onSave);
                                }
                            });
                    } else {
                        vals.author = null;
                        obj.save(vals, onSave);
                    }
               },
               error: function (obj, err) {
                    response.error(err.message + ': ' + vals.objectId);
               }
            });
    } else {
        response.error('Unable to update post');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just sort it out before you save?

Comment: I did as a work-around, but I was trying to do it as a beforeSave trigger since that seems like the 'right' way to do it.

Comment: I'd disagree as it means you're sending invalid data to the endpoint. If you were sending it to a cloud function to deal with then fine, but not directly to the save endpoint...

Comment: Just guessing, but I'd say that beforeSave isn't being called because the object (represented by request.params) isn't dirty, so save() decides to do nothing.

Comment: The cloud function, and the before save can be summed up as two lines from the client sdk side (in JS):  `myPost.set("author", Parse.User.current()); myPost.save()`

Comment: @danh The author won't always be the current user.

Comment: Okay.  Is the goal just to update a post and set its author?  This is easily done on client or cloud side (much more simply than the cloud code in the OP).  If that's the question, just let me know what inputs you have and what result you want.

Comment: The goal was to have one point where if a 'Post' is saved, it will find the Parse.User object based on the objectId. I guess since I'm using a cloud function for this instead of doing it client-side, I'm accomplishing that. I was just hoping to be able to use the beforeSave triggers to have a cleaner flow.